# SIGAR error: Operation not permitted

Tags: java, eclipse, sigar

I need a Java library that can tell me the current load of a server, so after searching I found that [SIGAR](https://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/Home#Home-download) is currently the most well known and well accepted amongst the community.

I am using Linux Mint 64-bit as operative system (it is a slight modification of Ubuntu) and since it is my first time using such a library I created a new project from zero using Eclipse and decided to install SIGAR on it by doing:

1. Download and extract the ZIP file
2. Create a folder called "libs" in my new Java Project
3. Copy the Sigar.jar and libsigar-amd64-linux.so files into the "libs" folder
4. Right Click Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External JARs -> Add Sigar.jar
5. Cross fingers and run project

However, when I run the project I get the following error:

```
/media/data/Users/pedro/SIGAR/libs/libsigar-amd64-linux.so: /media/data/Users/pedro/SIGAR/libs/libsigar-amd64-linux.so: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted
org.hyperic.sigar.SigarException: /media/data/Users/pedro/SIGAR/libs/libsigar-amd64-linux.so: /media/data/Users/pedro/SIGAR/libs/libsigar-amd64-linux.so: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted
    at org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.loadLibrary(Sigar.java:172)
    at org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.<clinit>(Sigar.java:100)
    at examples.Shell.<init>(Shell.java:50)
    at examples.SigarCommandBase.<init>(SigarCommandBase.java:75)
    at examples.CpuInfo.<init>(CpuInfo.java:36)
    at examples.CpuInfo.main(CpuInfo.java:97)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.getCpuInfoList()[Lorg/hyperic/sigar/CpuInfo;
    at org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.getCpuInfoList(Native Method)
    at examples.CpuInfo.output(CpuInfo.java:60)
    at examples.SigarCommandBase.processCommand(SigarCommandBase.java:186)
    at examples.CpuInfo.main(CpuInfo.java:97)
```

I checked the Internet and the `Operation not permitted` error usually occurs when I do not have the write or read permissions, but such is not the case.

Consequently I have some questions:

1. Have I messed up the installation?
2. If yes, how should I do it and can someone point me to a beginners tutorial?
3. If not, how can I fix the error? I already tried running Eclipse as root but it didn't work.

Thank you for your time, Pedro.

Comment: are you running this on Linux or on OS X?

Comment: Linux Mint, 64 bit version.

Comment: this is not a file permissions issue.  Some google searches suggest SELinux which sounds plausible.  Check your logs, e.g. /var/log/messages and, perhaps, /var/log/audit/audit.log

Comment: Now I am confused, I thought that problem was only happening in machines using RHEL. To be honest I dont even know what SELinux is and the folders you mentioned don't seem to exist :S

Comment: SELinux is not specific to RHEL.  Check /var/log/syslog instead of messages.

Comment: The file you mentioned does not exist as well. Still, I believe you were correct. It was SELinux, and I found a solution here:
http://objectmix.com/tcl/34666-failed-map-segment-shared-object-operation-not-permitted.html

They say just move the project into a new folder and that is what I did. Apparently it worked just fine. Thanks !